# Как вырезать запрос из ссылки?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите вырезать запрос из ссылки

> `http://site.com/keyword/запрос`

Буду очень признательна.

Answer (score 2):

```
var link = "http://site.com/keyword/запрос",
    query = link.slice(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
console.log(query); //выведет "запрос"
```